# Is there any way to do semi-anonymous commenting using Facebook login?

Tags: comments, social-network

I'm wondering if it is possible to allow a user to login for commenting via Facebook, but without having to setup a full Drupal account.

Is there anyway that allows this sort of semi-anonymous commenting?

The module I've seen don't really seem to allow this and there's no way I can tell to hook into Drupal anywhere that allows you to allow anonymous comments but with a Facebook login.

Comment: You mean comment as "Anonymous" but require a Facebook login? Why not just add Facebook commenting to the site?

Comment: I’m not quite sure on the differences. I’m assuming Facebook commenting on the site means that the comments are still stored on Facebook and it is tied to some Facebook application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use drupal module [Facebook comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_comments) or [Facebook comments block](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_comments_block) for the same.